# $http.get not working in Angular with different URLs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a working Angular-Module. When i change the URL (same JSON-File) it won't work. What do i wrong?

Working Module:

```
angular.module('destinationsApp', []).controller('destinationsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
   $http
    .get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MAHUKI-Webdesign/suntrips.github.io/master/main_sub_themes-light.json')
    .then(function(itemsResponse) {
        $scope.items = itemsResponse.data.main_themes;
```

Not working:

```
angular.module('destinationsApp', []).controller('destinationsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http
     .get('https://www.suntrips.de/import/main_sub_themes-light.json')
     .then(function(itemsResponse) {
        $scope.items = itemsResponse.data.main_themes;
```

Comment: what is the inside the response, itemsResponse?

Comment: any errors you see in console / Network tab?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing

Comment: then it's something related to the server, not your code, if it's ur server then try to allow-access-origin

Comment: What you mean with _what is the inside the response, itemsResponse?_ @Sletheren

Comment: @MarcHahn it's clear now, when it's a problem with CORS, then you have to edit the server to allow cross-origin access